# Python selenium web driver multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am crawling images with Python's selenium web driver(Chrome)

Can I use multiple drivers and have each driver crawl the image?

I want to do the following things with multiple processing

## source code

```
def crawl(searchText):
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\HYOWON\\Desktop\\Desktop\\Graduation\\Code\\Crawling\\chromedriver.exe')

  searchUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q={}&site=webhp&tbm=isch".format(searchText)

  driver.get(searchUrl)

  imgs_urls = []  # Url 저장 배열
  cnt = 0

  for j in range(20):
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-ri = '" + str(cnt + j) + "'] img")
      element.click()
      sleep(1)

      soup = create_soup() 

      for img in soup.find_all('img'):
          try:
              if img['src'].startswith('http') and img['src'].endswith('jpg'):  
                  imgs_urls.append(img['src'])
          except:  
              pass

  driver.close()
  return(imgs_urls)
```

## Modification code

```
 def crawl():
    imgs_urls = []
    for j in range(50):
      element1 = driver1.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-ri = '" + str(cnt) + "'] img")
      element2 = driver2.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-ri = '" + str(cnt) + "'] img")
      element3 = driver3.find_element_by_css_selector("div[data-ri = '" + str(cnt) + "'] img")

      element1.click()
      WebDriverWait(driver1, 1)
      soup1 = create_soup(driver1)

      for img in soup1.find_all('img'):
          try:
              if img['src'].startswith('http') and img['src'].endswith('jpg'):  # http로 시작 jpg로 끝나는것만
                imgs_urls.append(img['src'])
          except:  # 예외 pass
              pass

      element2.click()
      WebDriverWait(driver2, 1)
      soup2 = create_soup(driver2)

      for img in soup2.find_all('img'):
          try:
              if img['src'].startswith('http') and img['src'].endswith('jpg'):
                imgs_urls.append(img['src'])
          except:  # 예외 pass
              pass

      element3.click()
      WebDriverWait(driver3, 1)
      soup3 = create_soup(driver3)


      for img in soup3.find_all('img'):
          try:
              if img['src'].startswith('http') and img['src'].endswith('jpg'):
                imgs_urls.append(img['src'])
          except:  # 예외 pass
              pass

      cnt += 3

  return (imgs_urls)

def download_img(url, filename):
  full_name = str(filename) + ".jpg"
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'C:/Python/' + full_name)

for url in crawl():
  download_img(url, filename)
```

Comment: you need to implement an actual multiprocessing queue. Selenium is blocking meaning that it will stop your python from doing anything else. Driver 1 requests a page and Driver 2 can't do anything until driver 1 is done. This is solved with the multiprocessing library.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can! I've been thinking about using a multi-driver solution for a current project I'm working on as well.

In this example I'm just declaring the driver objects separately, though personally I would want to put them into some kind of array to reference them easier so you can iterate through them. Naturally this would make the structure of your code a bit different, though you shouldn't run into too many issues here.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

baseURL_1 = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"
baseURL_2 = "http://www.google.com/"

def main():
    init()
    initialPage()
    return

def init():
    global drv1
    global drv2

    chromedrvPath = "C:\\path_to_chrome\\chromedriver.exe"
    opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    opt.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
        'credentials_enable_service': False,
        'profile': {
            'password_manager_enabled': False
        }
    })
    drv1 = webdriver.Chrome(chromedrvPath,chrome_options=opt)
    drv2 = webdriver.Chrome(chromedrvPath,chrome_options=opt)

    return

def initialPage():
    navigate(baseURL_1,1)
    navigate(baseURL_2,2)
    return

def navigate(URL,d):
    if(d == 1):
        drv1.get(URL)
    if(d == 2):
        drv2.get(URL)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am trying to fix the above code in my way, but I get an error 403 forbidden Can I fix it? Please see the **Modification code**